# Unable to delete row from DataGrid By Delete Command in MVVM Light Project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

I design a view for taking input as much as user want from `Datagrid` UI.
Add `(+)` Button is work better means it add row one after another but when i press delete `(X)` button it throws an exception. Actually i want to remove particular row by clicking Delete Button. How i solve it?

**XMAL and GridView:**

[image]

Here is Code

```
 public class SaleViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

    private ViewModelLocator _locator;
    public SaleViewModel():base()
    {
        _locator = new ViewModelLocator();
        _myObject = new ObservableCollection<Sale>();
        _Item = new Sale();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Sale>();
        Items.Add(new Sale());
    }

    private RelayCommand _createNewRowCommand;
    public RelayCommand CreateNewRow
    {
        get { return _createNewRowCommand ?? (_createNewRowCommand = new RelayCommand(() => createNewRow())); }
    }

    void createNewRow()
    {
        Items.Add(new Sale());
    }

    private RelayCommand<Sale> _deleteRowCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Sale> DeleteRow
    {
        get { return _deleteRowCommand ?? (_deleteRowCommand = new RelayCommand<Sale>((p) => deleteRow(p))); }
    }

    void deleteRow(Sale p)
    {
            Items.Remove(p);
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Sale>(Items);
    }

    private RelayCommand _SaveItemCommand;
    public RelayCommand SaveItem
    {
        get { return _SaveItemCommand ?? (_SaveItemCommand = new RelayCommand(() => saveItem())); }
    }

    TestEntities3 context;
    void saveItem()
    {
        context = new TestEntities3(); ;

            context.Sales.Add(Item);
            context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Sale> _myObject;

    public ObservableCollection<Sale> Items
    {
        get { return _myObject; }
        set
        {
            _myObject = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
    private Sale _Item;

    public Sale Item
    {
        get { return _Item; }
        set { _Item = value; base.RaisePropertyChanged("Item"); }
    }

    public int? Qty
    {
        get { return _Item.Qty; }
        set { _Item.Qty = value; base.RaisePropertyChanged("Qty"); }
    }
 }
```

Please tell me where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try this?  `Items = new ObservableCollection<Sale>(Items);` after removing the row?

Comment: Please include your code sequences in your questions. Screenshots of them are no good.

Comment: Ya,Mr. Hari Prasad. i tried Items = new ObservableCollection<Sale>(Items); it.But exception occurs at :Items.Remove(p); this line

Comment: Ahh...the actual issue is you can't remove the Items, right?

Comment: yes,when i try to remove row by pressing delete button on my entry grid then exception occur but Items count is ok....

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(p!=null)
{
  Items.Remove(p);
  .......
}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".